# How can I reference a locator which is varying by a trailing digit in placeholder in xpath in Selenium Python/pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pytest

I am trying to click and add on few elements successively, which are in different div elements, but having placeholder varying by just a trailing digit as given below.

```
 input type="text" placeholder="Scale Point 1" value=""
```

```
 input type="text" placeholder="Scale Point 2" value=""
```

and so on.

I had tried using a for loop as below to avoid repetitive code blocks.

```
for i in range(1,6,1):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(abc.element_xpath+str(i)).click()
```

where element_xpath is

```
"//input[@placeholder="Scale Point"]"
```

Please suggest a way to avoid repetitive code block in Selenium Python (pytest) for the above case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put place holder in the `element_xpath` and insert the number with `format`

```
element_xpath = '//input[@placeholder="Scale Point {}"]'

for i in range(1,6,1):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(abc.element_xpath.format(i)).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to take care. As per the HTMLs you have shared:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Scale Point 1" value="">
```

and

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Scale Point 2" value="">
```

The value **Scale Point** is exactly not the *placeholder* of the elements but the partial *placeholder*. So effectively you need to change the definition of `element_xpath` following either of the following approaches:

- Using `%s`:

  ```
  "//input[starts-with(@placeholder, 'Scale Point') and contains(@placeholder, '%s')]"% str(i)
  ```
- Using `format()`:

  ```
  '//input[starts-with(@placeholder, "Scale Point") and contains(@placeholder, "{}")]'.format(str(i))
  ```

So, effectively your code block will be:

```
for i in range(1,6,1):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(abc.element_xpath).click()
```

Comment: @ArunSasi I understand you have accepted answer. Can you just confirm if either of the approaches works for you. Thanks